# How can I split a string into 2 strings using a delimiter

Tags: python, string, list, split, delimiter

The string is inside a list of strings and I'd like to split on the `?` character.

For example, splitting `['foo? bar\n', 'baz\n']` into `['foo\n', 'bar\n', 'baz\n']`.

(I just edited this question to include the newline characters.)

Comment: `foo = ["foo ? bar", "baz"]; bar = [foo[0].split("?"), "baz"]`

Comment: list comprehension way: 
`x = ['foo? bar', 'baz']; res = [j for i in x for j in i.split('?')]`

Comment: Can you be more specific about \n and space requirements?  First item has a leading space stripped and newline added?   Is it `strip()` + `\n` at end for each split result ?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way.

```
from itertools import chain

x = ['foo? bar', 'baz']

res = list(chain.from_iterable(i.strip().split('?') for i in x))

# ['foo', ' bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

That is fairly straight forward when using a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) like:

#### Code:

```
def split_str_in_list(a_list, split_char):
    for big_str in a_list:
        for s in big_str.split(split_char):
            yield s
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(list(split_str_in_list(['foo? bar', 'baz'], '? ')))
```

#### Results:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at a more explicit example and perhaps easier to understand.

```
def split_text(input_list):
    result = []
    # iterate through every string from input_list
    for item in input_list:
        #split a string by '? '; splitted is a list with minimum 1 element(item) when item does not contain '? '
        splitted = item.split('? ')
        # iterate through this list and append every string at result list
        for i in splitted:
            result.append(i)
    return result

input_list = ['foo? bar', 'baz']
print(split_text(input_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach :

```
df=['foo? bar\n', 'baz\n']


new_list=[]
for i in df:
    if '?' in i:
        spli_data=i.split('?')
        for sub_ in spli_data:
            if '\n' not in sub_:
                new_list.append(sub_+'\n')
            else:
                new_list.append(sub_)

    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```

output:

```
['foo\n', ' bar\n', 'baz\n']
```